# ID sendo criado e não começando com 0 - Oracle 11g

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou estudando Banco de Dados, usando Oracle 11g e fazendo as tabelas no SQLPLUS.
Eu crio a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPRAS (ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, VALOR NUMBER, DATA DATE, 
OBSERVACOES VARCHAR2(30), RECEBIDO CHAR CHECK (RECEBIDO IN (0,1)));
```

E logo após, crio uma sequência:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ;
```

Com isso, eu vou inserir os dados com este comando:

```
INSERT INTO COMPRAS (ID, VALOR, DATA, OBSERVACOES, RECEBIDO) VALUES 
(ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 100, ’12-MAY-2007’, ‘Compras de Maio’, ‘1’);
```

E para ver os dados inserido na tabela, eu rodo:

```
SELECT * FROM COMPRAS;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Provavelmente ocorreram dois erros antes de você acertar o comando INSERT. Mesmo quando ocorre um erro a sequencia é atualizada e por isso podem existir buracos.

Comment: Ola @Vagner, não altere sua pergunta para indicar que você conseguiu achar uma solução, fico feliz em saber que você quer ajudar outros com o mesmo problema, nesse caso a melhor opção é você responder sua própria pergunta, mas tarde o sistema vai liberar você para aceitar sua própria resposta. Dica: como você achou a solução na documentação vale a pena você adicionar o link da documentação na sua resposta. =D --- Vou reverter sua edição, você pode ver-la [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/403968/revisions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução que resolve este problema é que a documentação do Oracle 11g é diferente das demais pelo visto, dando uma pesquisada nas documentações eu encontrei que não é só preciso criar a sequência com este comando abaixo:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ;
```

Na documentação do Oracle 11g, é preciso fazer desta forma, segue abaixo:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ID_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE NOCYCLE;
```